# How to share folder from Multipass to Host?

Tags: macos, multipass

I'm using multipass(Ubuntu 20.04, local.driver=virtualbox).

How I can share folder from multipass to macOS(host), I need to have the possibility to change files from the host on multipass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a network bridge to access the VM from outside, using the `--network` parameter when launching the instance. Then, you can share a folder from the instance using the SMB protocol (installing the `samba` package on the instance and configuring it in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`). And you'll see the share on your Finder.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a `multipass mount` command.

```
% multipass mount --help
Usage: multipass mount [options] <source> <target> [<target> ...]
Mount a local directory inside the instance. If the instance is
not currently running, the directory will be mounted
automatically on next boot.
```

So, for example.

- `primary` - name of the container,
- `./output` - local dir (on the host)
- `/target` - dir in the container

```
multipass mount ./output primary:/target
```

This mounted local dir at the path `./output` to container named `primary`.

Now, you can go inside the `primary`, and look up the mount point:

```
multipass shell primary
$ mount | grep output
:/Users/folex/output on /output type fuse.sshfs.
```

Now you can use that directory to share files.

#### `multipass info`

To see the mount from the host:

```
multipass info primary

Name:           primary
State:          Running
IPv4:           192.168.64.2
Release:        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Image hash:     9256911742f0 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
CPU(s):         2
Load:           0.04 0.10 0.04
Disk usage:     3.4GiB out of 4.8GiB
Memory usage:   154.8MiB out of 962.2MiB
Mounts:         /Users/folex/output => /output
                    UID map: 501:default
                    GID map: 20:default
```

*`multipass` version: `1.12.2+mac`.*